# Unable to show positive and negative values together using D3 js

Tags: d3.js, graph, bar-chart, d3-graphviz

I am using d3.js but I am unable to show both values together on graph that is
positive values above the x axis and negative value below x axis ...

I tried below code

```
var bar = g.selectAll(".bar").data(data);
        var barColorClass = 'blue-bar';
        var transitionOrigin =  D3Graph.height - 1;
        
        var rect = bar.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar "+barColorClass)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * unit; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return transitionOrigin;})
          .attr("width", unit);
        
        rect.transition(t)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            
                return (y(d.amount) < 0) ? (D3Graph.height + 3) : (D3Graph.height - y(d.amount));
        
        }).attr("y", function(d) {
            
                return (y(d.amount) < 0) ? (-1 * 3) : y(d.amount);
                
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a canonical example you would adjust the `y` and `height` of the rects based on if they are positive or negative:

```
.attr('y', (d) => d.y > 0 ? y(d.y) : y(0))
.attr('height', (d) => d.y > 0 ? y(0) - y(d.y) : y(d.y) - y(0))
```

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script>
    const margin = {
        top: 30,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 70,
        left: 60
      },
      width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const svg = d3
      .select('#chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    const data = [{
        x: 'one',
        y: 10,
      },
      {
        x: 'two',
        y: -10,
      },
      {
        x: 'three',
        y: 5,
      },
      {
        x: 'four',
        y: -5,
      },
      {
        x: 'five',
        y: 15,
      },
      {
        x: 'six',
        y: -15,
      },
    ];

    // X axis
    const x = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(
        data.map((d) => d.x)
      )
      .padding(0.2);

    svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)')
      .style('text-anchor', 'end');

    // Add Y axis
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data.map((d) => d.y))).range([height, 0]);
    svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Bars
    svg
      .selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', (d) => x(d.x))
      .attr('y', (d) => d.y > 0 ? y(d.y) : y(0))
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', (d) => d.y > 0 ? y(0) - y(d.y) : y(d.y) - y(0))
      .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show me how can it be implemented using my code ?? Because I tried integrating it but cant get it

Comment: If you want further help, you'll need to update your question with a complete code sample.  Going to be tough for me to "fix your code" with what you posted.

Comment: Thanks @Mark it worked for me as suggested by you..